# Difficulty in running provisioning utility that require full control on Tenant - O365 Dedicated

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, office365

Recently I stumbled upon a situation wherein I had to create a utility to perform some activities on the tenant that required full control on the tenant of our O365 Dedicated platform. I referred a few articles on MSDN and Technet and I believe I reached closed to achieving it but got stuck at a point. Below is a brief point by point summary of my situation:

- As stated in the article    https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn799022.aspx, I    discovered that the tenant admin URL for dedicated platform is     [/msotenantcontext]. So I used this tenant admin    URL to get the context for the tenant a console application that I    was developing for getting access to the tenant admin.
- As step 2, I created the App ID and App Secret and placed it correctly in the App.config.
- Now I needed to assign full control on the tenant  to the App Identity I created. So I went to the    [yourwebappurl/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx] page, I looked up the    desired App ID and added the required XML in the permission section.
- On clicking on submit I was redirected to the confirmation page where the Trust It button was disabled and a message was shown which    stated - Sorry, only tenant administrators can add or give access to    this app.
- On searching a bit, I stumbled on this article - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn609806.aspx. I started    following the steps mentioned in it.
- I went to the  /sites/appcatalog site. The article mentioned that in the app catalog site I need to go to Site    Settings -> Cross site app permission(under User and permissions). To    my disappointment I found out that the ‘Cross site app permission’    link was not present.
- I searched the net a lot but couldn’t find a solution to this. I did find a couple of forums where users had mentioned such a    situation but there wasn’t really a solution in there.

It would be great if someone could help me figure out why the ‘Cross site app permission’ link is not appearing in my case. I have been struggling since quite a few days with it.

Thanks in advance!!